# How to use binding in .Net Maui?

Tags: c#, maui

I'm creating a custom view in .Net Maui 7 as follows :

XAML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:HS="clr-namespace:MyApp.Controls;assembly=MyApp"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:MyViewVM"             
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:MyApp.Controls"            
             x:Class="MyApp.Controls.MyView">

    <Grid RowDefinitions="*" x:Name="MyNiceGrid" ColumnDefinitions="*">        
        ... something               
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

C#

```
public partial class MyView : Grid
{        
    MyViewVM myViewVM;
    
    public MyView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.myViewVM = new MyViewVM();                        
    }
}
```

View Model in C#

```
public partial class MyViewVM : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]        
    bool started;       
}
```

The view is supposed to be added to other pages or other custom views. So I can't use the property binding context for the binding :

```
this.BindingContext = this.myViewVM;    // I don't want to use that
```

So I'm adding binding properties in XAML as follows :

```
<Label Text="Something" IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Object myViewVM}, Path=Started}"></Label>
```

When changing the binding property value (in this case named **Started**) nothing happens to the label added. while it's supposed to be invisible when the property Started is false.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> The view is supposed to be added to other pages or other custom views. So I can't use the property binding context for the binding :

```
this.BindingContext = this.myViewVM;    // I don't want to use that
```

You need this.

There are no reasons for not setting the ViewModel as binding context.
You can use it unlimited amount of times and places.

If you want to use it multiple times in one page, you make something like this:

```
<MyGrid BindingContext={Binding ViewModelGrid1}..
<MyGrid BindingContext={Binding ViewModelGrid2}..
```

If you want to use it in different pages, each page has different ViewModel object anyway, so there is no problem also.

Other Views have ViewModels, that contain this ViewModel.
You can, and you should use BindingContext. Do not try to invent new MVVM. You will only make a mess with your architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code, it works well.

Page.xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:MauiApp3.ViewModels" 
             x:Class="MauiApp3.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <ViewModel:VM/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout Spacing="25" Padding="30,0" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Label Text="Hello, World!" 
                   IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}" 
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            <Button Text="click" 
                    Command="{Binding TapCommand}"/>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    bool isVisible = true;
    public bool IsVisible
    {
        get => isVisible;
        set
        {
            isVisible = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsVisible));
        }
    }

    public ICommand TapCommand { get; set; }

    public VM()
    {
        isVisible = true;
        TapCommand = new Command(Show);
    }
    private void Show()
    {
        IsVisible = !IsVisible;
    }
    
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```